# Як назвати оформлення отримання новин в мережі?

Tags: вживання-слів, значення-слів, помилки

Ми підписуємося (що є суржиковим висловом) на друзів, новини, розсилки в мережі.  Як це назвати?  Стандартне українське "передплата" ніяк не годиться для визначення дії, завдяки якій ми отримуємо регулярні повідомлення з інтернет-ресурсів.

Comment: А поясніть, чому не підходить *«підписуватися (на джерело)»*? Якщо бентежить те, що воно схоже на дієслово «ставити підпис», то можна просто використовувати *«виписувати (джерело)»*, чи є інші причини?

Comment: Професор Пономарів, мабуть, теж читає SE, адже у сьогоднішньому [блозі](http://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blog-olexandr-ponomariv-40718117) висловлює свій варіант (хоч вам (як і мені) він і не до вподоби): "-...читач запитує, як називати користувачів, що підписалися на сторінку в соцмережі. - Таких користувачів можна називати *передплатниками*".

Comment: [Доповню.](http://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blog-olexandr-ponomariv-39076821) **Львівʼянин Андрій Горбунов пише: Борис Антоненко-Давидович стверджує, що правильно не підписка, а передплата. Але як же це слово можна застосовувати тепер, коли маємо інтернет та инші засоби?** Антоненко-Давидович має цілковиту рацію. Це був видатний борець за культуру української мови. Слово передплата набуло нового значення, і не треба вигадувати якихось нових слів. Нам треба вчитися в греків, чехів та инших народів, які навіть для слова компʼютер використовують свої лексеми, надаючи їм нового значення.

Comment: Бачу, що конструктивної ідеї поки що нема. Будемо жити ) з часом з'явиться.

Comment: "не треба вигадувати якихось нових слів" - вражаюче! життя змінюється, а нових слів нам не треба, отакої

Comment: Див. також: [«Як перекласти слово „подписчик“»](/q/5121).

Answer (score 4):

Фактично у соціальних мережах, наскільки я можу судити, це можуть бути дві різні речі:

1. Ви додаєте когось до переліку своїх «друзів» (реєструєте в системі те, що хтось Вам «друг»). Тоді так можна і сказати:

   - > додати когось у «друзі»;
   - > додати когось у список «друзів»;
   - > позначити когось як «друга»;
   - > зареєструвати «дружбу» з кимось.
2. Ви можете погодитися отримувати новини від певної людини, сторінки, групи; англійською мовою це зазвичай називається «to follow» — слідкувати, стежити, відстежувати. Facebook застосовує переклад «стежити» або «відстежувати». Наприклад, можна:

   - > стежити за певною розсилкою;
   - > стежити за новинами від певного «друга»;
   - > стежити за певною сторінкою.

Ці два поняття фактично не пов'язані. Хоча за замовчуванням багато соціальних мереж при додаванні когось Вам у «друзі» автоматично призначають Вас стежити за його новинами — але це необов'язково: Ви можете відмовитися стежити за новинами когось із Ваших «друзів» (не вилучаючи їх зі списку), або, навпаки, згодитися стежити за новинами людей, що не є Вашими «друзями».

P.S.: Як перекласти англійське «to subscribe» (і чи є «підписатись» суржиковим) — питання окреме, мені важко сказати. Але багато соціальних мереж / сайтів навіть англійською обходяться лише «to follow», не використовуючи «to subscribe».

Comment: Моє питання стосується саме "подписки". Що на людину з її новинами, що на новини від ресурсу.

Answer (score 4):

[Запис](http://sum.in.ua/s/zapys) чи [записування](http://sum.in.ua/s/zapysuvannja) — дія за значенням [записувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/zapysuvaty)·[ся](http://sum.in.ua/s/zapysuvatysja)

> **Записувати**, ую, уєш, *недок*., **записати**, ишу, ишеш, *док*., *перех*.
>
> **2.** *кого*. Заносити, вносити у список, реєстр і т. ін. *В тому [кривдянському] посаді і в церковних метриках, і в посадських, і поліцейських книгах були позаписувані якісь невмираючі люди: вони ніколи не вмирали, бо на їх місце зараз записували нових українських утікачів і давали їм прізвища записаних в книгах небіжчиків* ([Нечуй-Левицький](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B9-%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), II, 1956, 220); *— Усі прийшли? — «Всі». — Не прийшов Безик Олекса. — «Я тут...» — Треба всіх записати* ([Михайло Коцюбинський](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%86%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), II, 1955, 99); *Чорнокнижний заклопотано подивився на тюремника, запитав, кого він привів, несхвально похитав головою і звелів підписареві записати в арештантську книгу імʼя та прізвище старого* ([Михайло Стельмах](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), I, 1962, 450);
>
> **//**  *розм.* Заносити кого-небудь і **до списку**, зараховуючи, приймаючи **або** влаштовуючи, віддаючи **кудись**. *Батьки приводили дітей записувати **до** школи* ([Михайло Коцюбинський](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%86%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), I, 1955, 322); *— Чого приїхала? **До** комуни записувати?* ([Василь Еллан](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%95%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9), II, 1958, 8); *— Ходім! Князь велів записати тебе **у** балет* ([Гнат Хоткевич](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87_%D0%93%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), I, 1966, 114); *Лагутіна вона сама записала **в** легкоатлети* ([Олесь Гончар](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%80_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C_%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), Людина.., 1960, 50);
>
> **Записуватися**, уюся, уєшся, *недок*., **записатися**, ишуся, ишешся, *док*.
>
> **1.** Вносити своє імʼя до якого-небудь [списку](http://sum.in.ua/s/peredplachuvaty), реєстру і т. ін. *Марійка дуже хвилювалась — і коли записувалась.. на прийом до лікаря, і коли чекала своєї черги* ([Олесь Донченко](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C_%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), V, 1957, 430); *Належить мерщій зібрати гроші від тих, хто записався та ще не віддав* ([Панас Мирний](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9), V, 1955, 425);

*Записатися у друзі • записатися до новин • запис*·*атися до читання • запис*·*ати*·*ся до отримання • запис*·*атися до розсилок*

---

Comment: О, оце добре! Тепер я знаю як літературно перекласти *subscribe*. Бо раніше мені (мабуть, як і авторці) теж в голову йшло переважно ***під**писатися* («я підписався на новини», «мережа сама підписала мене на новини») — але із ***за**писати(ся)* значно логічніше.

Comment: "Записатися на розсилку" звучить незграбно, якийсь неживий конструкт. Але це хоча б не суржик.

Comment: Справді, звучить дешчо незграбно, бо за прикладами мусить бути не _на_, а _до_.

Comment: Є суттєвий недолік - немає однокорінного іменника. Я записався до вас у друзі, т.т. я - ваш "**записник**" :)

Comment: @finesoul Чому нема? Ьа вже розгльанув в питаньі [Як перекласти слово “подписчик”](/a/5128/585). Коротко: _писар_ — _записар_. Можна також _записець_ — _писець_.

Answer (score 4):

Майже щодня кожний користувач всесвітньої «павутини»,
опрацьовуючи матеріали в електронних книгозбірнях,
реєструючись у соціальних мережах, щось купуючи в Інтернет-
магазинах, викладаючи фото в Instagram чи переглядаючи
стрічку новин за кавою, бачить різні слова на позначення
поняття, якому відповідає англ. **subscribe** – підписуватися,
приєднуватися.

На російськомовних сайтах зазвичай це
**подписчик** , а на українськомовних трапляються варіанти:
**підписник** , **підписчик** , **підписант** , **абонент**, **передплатник**.

Чи коректні наведені слововживання? Чи відповідають
вони літературній нормі української мови? В 11-томному
Словнику української мови (1970-1980) слів «**підписник**» і
«**підписант**» не зафіксовано. Є лише іменник **підписка**

> 1. Дія за знач. Підписати, підписувати, і підписатися, підписуватися.
> 2. Письмове зобов’язання або потвердження чогось (СУМ, VI, 482)

та дієслова **підписуватися**, підписатися

> 1. Ставити свій підпис під чим-небудь.
> 2. Виявляти бажання, згоду на участь у чому-небудь (у збиранні коштів, пожертвувань і т. ін.), звичайно записуючись у список (СУМ, VI, 482).

Кодифікована в СУМ іменникова назва **передплатник**

> той, хто передплатив яке-небудь друковане видання (СУМ, VI, 174),

а дієслово **передплачувати**, **передплатити** має таке
тлумачення:

> складати угоду про надсилання друкованого видання з попередньою його
>   оплатою та одержувати це видання за такою угодою (СУМ, VI, 174).

З появою нових реалій помічаємо нові контексти
слововживань **передплата**, **передплатник**, **абонент**,
**абонемент**.

На різних сайтах з оплати комунальних послуг часто
трапляється слово **абонент** на позначення користувача цього
типу електронних ресурсів і відповідно – енерго-, газо- чи
водопостачання тощо. СУМ тлумачить слово **абонент** як
"той, хто користується абонементом" (СУМ, I, 4), а відповідно
**абонемент** –

> 1. Право користуватися, за плату або безплатно, чим-небудь (телефоном, місцем у театрі, книжками з бібліотеки і т. ін.) протягом певного
>      часу; документ, що посвідчує це право.
> 2. Реєстрова бібліотечна картка читача абонемента» (СУМ, I, 4).

У «Словнику термінів інформаційних систем і технологій»
(К., 2008) В. Дербенцева та ін. **абонент** – це

> юридична або фізична особа, що користується послугами обчислювальної
>   системи (с.7).

У цьому ж словнику зафіксовано й лексему
**підписувач** (англ. **subscriber**), проте з іншим відтінком значення,
аніж перелічені в назві контекстуальні синоніми:

> особа, яка має таємний ключ та використовує його для накладання електронного
>   цифрового підпису на електронні документи (с. 142).

*Тоді як правильно називати тих, кого прагнуть «накручувати»
(штучно збільшувати кількість) у соцмережах: **передплатники**,
**абоненти**, **підписники**, **підписчики** чи **підписанти**?*

На нашу
думку, якщо йдеться про надання *попередньо оплачених
інформаційних послуг* (отримання електронних передплатних
видань, користування платними сегментами сайтів тощо),
доцільно вживати слово **передплатник**.

Користувача сайту – *платника послуг, скажімо, Київгазу*,
Укртелекому, Дніпроводоканалу та ін., логічно назвати
**абонентом**, оскільки він отримує право за плату (після надання
послуги) користуватися водою, газом, електроенергією,
телефоном і т. ін., фіксувати показники лічильників і
контролювати платежі на відповідному сайті.

Словник української мови (2012) подає слово **підписант** –

> той, хто підписав колективне клопотання, звернення, заяву (с. 774)

– зі стилістичною ремаркою розмовне. У засобах
масової комунікації ця лексема іноді вживається з негативною
конотацією, тоді як в офіційно-діловій сфері має стилістично
нейтральне значення і все ширше застосовується для номінації
уповноваженої особи, що має юридичне право підпису
(пор. у словнику Л.В. Туровської, Л.М. Василькової «Нові
слова та значення» (2008): **підписант** –

> той, хто підписує офіційні документи (с. 184)

). Нині набувають популярності
електронні петиції до органів влади, тому можна передбачити
зміну в стилістичному забарвленні й термінологізації слова
підписант на означення осіб, що в такий спосіб здійснили
своє волевиявлення.

Не радимо вживати лексему **підписчик**, кальку з російської
мови, утворену за не властивою українській мові словотвірною
моделлю називання осіб.

Користувача, який за допомогою опцій «Подобається» або
«Підписатися» на якомусь електронному ресурсі чи сторінці
в соціальній мережі зголосився на безоплатне отримання
актуальної інформації, реклами та новин, доцільно називати
**підписнúк**.

(с) [Ангеліна Ганжа (Пономаренко)](https://scholar.google.com.ua/citations?user=S1OigVoAAAAJ&hl=uk)- кандидат філологічних наук, Інститут української мови

Оригінал знайшов [тут](http://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/122969/38-Ganzha.pdf?sequence=1)

P.S. Тобто підписатися, [підписка](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidpyska) та підписник.

Comment: Оркім _subscribe_ ье шче _follow_. Ріжницье в тим, шчо перше маье повідомьеньа до е-пошти.