# Як перекласти слово "подписчик"

Tags: переклад, from-russian

[Російсько-український словник](http://www.%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0.%D1%80%D1%84/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA) пропонує варіант "[передплатник](http://sum.in.ua/s/peredplatnyk)". Однак, я не впевнений, що це слово завжди буде доречно так перекладати (також варто врахувати, яке воно має визначення в СУМі - "Той, хто передплатив яке-небудь друковане видання", а як бути із "подписчиками" в соц. мережах, Юутб-каналів тощо. Гадаю слово "передплатник" тут не буде доречним, хоча б через те, що в ньому є частина "[платник](http://sum.in.ua/s/platnyk)").

Другий варіант, який мені вдалося знайти - "[абонент](https://uk.glosbe.com/ru/uk/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA)". Знову ж таки, мені здається, що воно не завжди підійде, бо, наприклад, дивно буде почути: "У мене сто абонентів в Інстаграмі". Гадаю, що таке речення зараз могло б спантеличити кого-небудь.

Тобто цікавить як саме ми можемо перекласти це слово українською, щоб вживати його коли говоримо про соціальні мережі, Інтернет тощо.

Comment: Запитанье-родич: [Як назвати оформлення отримання новин в мережі?](/q/2551/)

Answer (score 6):

[послідовник](http://sum.in.ua/s/poslidovnyk), [послідувач](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%87&dicts=1&highlight=on) та [підписник](http://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/122969/38-Ganzha.pdf?sequence=1)

---

1. [Послідо́вник](http://sum.in.ua/s/poslidovnyk), а, чол. Той, хто наслідує кого-, що-небудь, іде за чиїмсь прикладом.

   > Новітнім послідовникам Наполеона не слід забувати
   >   про сумну долю його походу в Росію! (Літературна Україна, 16.X 1962,
   >   2);
   >   *Приклад передовиків знаходить послідовників насамперед там, де
   >   партійні організації постійно тримають цю справу в полі свого зору
   >   (Радянська Україна, 22.III 1961, 2);
   >
   >   Безстрашність викликає багато
   >   послідовників (Іван І. Волошин, Дні.., 1958, 159);*
2. [Послідувач](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%87&dicts=1&highlight=on)… "по" — теперешній час; "слідувач" — той хто іде за кимось (дивись слово "слідчий").
3. [Підписник](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&dicts=9&highlight=on).
   сенс полягає в дії людини за власним бажанням приєднатися до чогось.

   > *…зголосився на безоплатне отримання актуальної інформації, реклами та
   >   новин, доцільно називати підписни́к.* — Ангеліна Ганжа

---

Перші два зустрічаються в аніме спільнотах, третій у соц. мережі ВК та з усіх трьох варіантів не подобається третій.

Comment: Додам, що _послідувач_ — доволі рідковживаний варіант ([лише 3 трапляння в ГРАК-10](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=wordrow&word=послідувач.*)), хоча в деяких аспектах він мені подобається навіть більше за _послідовник_.

Answer (score 5):

Якщо ми говоримо про соцмережі, то треба дивитись на оригінал (тобто англійську версію), а не на спосіб запозичення/перекладу іншою, хай і близькою, мовою.

"Subscriber" цілком доречно перекладається словом "підписник". "Sub-" у цьому випадку означає "під-", "scribe" — "писати". Якщо ми подивимось на типові значення цього слова [у словнику](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subscribe), то побачимо, що багато з них обертаються навколо власне підпису:

> 1 : to write (one's name) underneath : sign

> 2 a : to sign (something, such as a document) with one's own hand in token of consent or obligation
>
> b : to set one's name to a paper in token of promise to give something (such as a sum of money)

Тому перекладати "subscriber" як "підписник" вважаю цілком доречним і ніяким не русизмом, щонайменше у контексті соцмереж та подібного.

P.S. Одне із значень — "підтримувати":

> 3 : to feel favorably disposed

що є і в українській ("підписуюсь під кожним її словом").

Answer (score 3):

Більшість таких, що вже існують англомовних аналогів на сьогодні лиш шукають своє місце в нашій мові. Годі шукати точного відповідника в цьому разі, якщо його за змістом не існувало досі. Бо не було такого поняття як такого.

Я так розумію, Ви шукаєте аналог англійського [Follower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Follower), якщо подивитися [варіанти на це слово](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=follower&highlight=on) в перекладацьких ресурсах, то найближчими за змістом можна визначити - палкий прихильник, стійкий послідовник.

На мій погляд можна вживати звичайне
"[читач](http://sum.in.ua/?swrd=chytach)",[читачі сторінки](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?iquery=%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%96%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8&corpname=grac10&corpus-search-form=true)". Що відповідатиме по суті і є зрозумілим та [вживаним](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?iquery=%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%87&corpname=grac10&corpus-search-form=true).
Також для певних варіантів за контекстом можуть бути використані "прихильник", "спостерігач".

Comment: "Follower" по сенсу ближче до чогось типу "відслідковувач", як на мене. У контексті соцмереж "to follow" означає радше "слідКувати", а не "слідувати" ([див. значення 8:a,b,e](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/follow)).

Answer (score 0):

Якшчо продовжувати власну думку зі запитаня-родича, де теж є обуренє на слово однопневого *передплатити*:

> [Як назвати оформлення отримання новин в мережі?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2551/)

Там я пораяв пня *запис*. Тому коли рухати в такому ж напрямі, то отримую *записар*, як [*писар*](http://sum.in.ua/s/pysar) від *пис*. Матимемо:

> Маю 100 записарів в Інстаґрамі

Правда, словників з таким словом нема. Хіба шчо не јменника *записаниј*:

> [ЗАПИ́САНИЙ, *а*, *е*.](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=31381&page=1021) Дієпр. пас. до *записа́ти*.

Comment: Це якийсь пекельний діалект. Ми шукаємо письмову загальноприйнятну норму.